# Laravel HasMany WhereNotIn Query

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

> **Problem:** I'm trying to query a PeopleType to find all the courses where a person isn't associated.

I have 4 tables

1. People
2. PeopleTypes
3. Courses
4. People_Courses
5. PeopleType_Courses

I have the following relationships

**PERSON MODEL**

```
public function getPeopleType() {
  return $this->belongsTo('App\PeopleType','type_id');
}

public function getCourses() {
  return $this->belpngsToMany('App\Course','People_Courses','person_id','course_id');
}
```

**PEOPLE_TYPE MODEL**

```
public function getPeople() {
  return $this->hasMany('App\Person','type_id');
}

public function getCourses() {
  return $this->belpngsToMany('App\Course','PeopleType_Courses','people_type_id','course_id');
}
```

**My attempt:**

```
$peopleType = \App\PeopleType::FindOrFail(1);
$courses = $peopleType->getCourses()->whereNotIn('id', function($q) use($person) {
                $q->select('course_id')
                  ->from('People_Courses')
                    ->where('person_id', $person->id);
           })->get();
```

**My response:**

> Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in IN/ALL/ANY
>   subquery is ambiguous

**People Courses Table Schematic**

```
Schema::create('People_Courses', function (Blueprint $table) {
   $table->increments('id');
   $table->integer('course_id');
   $table->integer('person_id');
);
```

**PeopleType_Courses Table Schematic**

```
Schema::create('PeopleType_Courses', function (Blueprint $table) {
   $table->increments('id');
   $table->integer('course_id');
   $table->integer('people_type_id');
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're working on relations that have similar column name being selected in the query you need to resolve the ambiguity by specifying the table name with the column. e.g:

```
$peopleType->getCourses()->whereNotIn('courses.id', function($q)...  //courses.id
```